# empty string in D programing language

Tags: arrays, string, d

What is empty string in D programing language?

String is array of characters ( http://dlang.org/arrays.html#strings )

 Probably: `alias immutable(char)[] string`

Based on that *empty string* should be an *empty array*. But then, what kind of thing  the *empty array* is?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

any (non-static) array is essentially a struct with a pointer to the start of the memory block the array is contained in and a length

an empty array just has length==0

Answer (score 6):

An empty `string` *is* an empty array. It's an empty array of type `immutable(char)[]`. An empty array is an array with length 0. I don't understand what's hard to understand about that.

Regardless, if you want to understand arrays in D better, then you should read [this article](http://dlang.org/d-array-article.html). It's one of the things that every D programmer should read and should give you a much better understanding of arrays in D.

Comment: "I don't understand what's hard to understand about that."
After 'ratchet freak' answer its was really simple to understand. (array=struct{pointer;length})
At first I thought (incorrectly) that `array` is only pointer to allocated memory block, so empty `array` of size 2 would be pointer to memory block of size 2, and size 0 array would be pointer to memory block of size 0. But memory block this was kind of nonsense (thought maybe NULL pointer or pointer pointing to some _special_ memory address is said to be empty..)
Thanks for the link